# pygame 画像を読み込めない

Tags: python, 画像

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import sys

def main():
    (w,h)=(400,400)
    (x,y)=(200,200)
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h),0,32)
    screen=pygame.display.get_surface()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Test")

    bg= pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\bg.png").convert_alpha
    rect_bg=bg.get_rect()

    player=pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\player.png").convert_alpha
    rect_player=player.get_rect()
    rect_player.center=(x,y)

    while(1):
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(30)
        screen.fill((0,20,0,0))
        screen.blit(bg,rect_bg)
        screen.blit(player,rect_player)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

main()
```

と入力すると

```
    11     pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Test")
     12 
---> 13     bg= pygame.image.load("C:\prog\python\pygame\bg.png").convert_alpha
     14     rect_bg=bg.get_rect()
     15 

error: Couldn't open C:\prog\python\pygamg.png
```

というエラーが発生して、bg.pngが開けませんでした。画像のファイルはこのコードが入っているファイルと一緒の場所にあるのになぜ開けないのでしょうか？

Comment: [pygame.image.load](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) には、"Pygame may not always be built to support all image formats. At minimum it will support uncompressed BMP. If pygame.image.get_extended() returns 'True', you should be able to load most images (including PNG, JPG and GIF)." と書かれています。まずは`pygame.image.get_extended()` を実行して結果を確認してみる事をお勧めします。

Comment: @metropolisn  実行してみた結果1と出力されました。これはどういう意味でしょうか。また、このコードは別サイトのチュートリアルからそのままとってきており、画像も同じのを使っているのですがそのサイトでは反応しています、、、

Comment: `1` というのは `True` という意味ですので、PNG format の画像ファイルを読み込む事が可能です。そうなりますと、パス名(文字列)の問題ということになります。

Answer (score 0):

原因はパスの区切りをバックスラッシュ`\` 1つだけにしていることと、ファイル名の最初の文字が`b`で`\b`となってバックスペースのエスケープシーケンスが成立してしまったことにあるでしょう。

エラーメッセージに`error: Couldn't open C:\prog\python\pygamg.png`とあって、ソースのファイル名`"C:\prog\python\pygame\bg.png"`からバックスペース(直前の1文字削除)処理によって`e\b`が削除されています。
`\p`はエスケープシーケンスでは無いのでそのままになっています。

こちらにエスケープシーケンス等を含む文字列リテラルの仕様があります。
[2.4.1. 文字列およびバイト列リテラル](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

対策は以下のいずれかですね。

- パスの区切りを`\`バックスラッシュではなく`/`スラッシュに変える
- バックスラッシュのままにするのなら以下のいずれか

  - バックスラッシュを連続させて`\\`というように2つにする
  - `r"..."`というように文字列のダブルクォーテーションの前に`r`または`R`を付ける

エスケープシーケンスになってしまう文字の前のバックスラッシュだけ2つにするという手もありますが、何が対象かを覚えておかなくてはいけないし、パスを書くたびに考慮しなければならないので煩雑になります。

Comment: パス区切りの問題であっていると思います。文字列のエスケープは、認識されないものであればそのままになります。例えば質問の例であれば、「\b」はバックスペースになりますが、「\p」は「\p」のままになります。テストでうまくいっているのは、たまたまエスケープとして認識されていなかっただけではないですか。

Comment: @katsuko さん、ありがとうございます。エラーメッセージを良く見ていませんでしたね。@nekketsuuu さん指摘とも併せて全面的に改稿しました。